# Definition of 'this' keyword in .NET documentation

Tags: c#, constructor, this

I currently trying to learn about 'this' keyword, in .NET documentation is:

> The this keyword refers to the current instance of the class and is
>   also used as a modifier of the first parameter of an extension method.

First thing I learned with 'this' keyword was how to resolve scope ambiguity, when class data field have same name as for example parameter in constructor. Like this:

```
class Person
{
    public string name;

    public Person(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

here is used 'this' keyword to inform C# compiler that  I want to use variable named 'name' and it should be from current class instance scope rather then from method scope. For example if I create object of Person class on managed heap and reference to this object I assigned to variable named 'p1', statement 'this.name' would in fact be 'p1.X' (I know I cant write it to code like that, but just for better imagination). If it is right like that, then definition from .NET documentation make sense to me for this example.

but what if I use 'this' keyword for chaining constructors?

again I know what it does, but I really don't know what 'this' keyword is using from current class instance? In first example with scope ambiguity it make sense, but in chaining constructors I really don't know what it has to do with any class instance, as it doesn't use anything from instance, it just passing forward the incoming arguments to the master constructor.

Example of chaining constructors:

```
class Person
{
    public string name;
    public int? age;

    public Person(string name): this(name, null) { }

    public Person(string initName, int? initAge)
    {
        name = initName;
        age = initAge;
    }
}
```

So my question is, because in documentation is written, that this keyword refers to the current instance of the class: 
*What 'this' keyword is referring from current instance of the class when you use it with chaining constructors?*

Thank you for answers

Comment: once you enter a constructor, you have entered "this" instance of the class

*some terms and conditions may apply

Comment: `public MyClass(string name, string id) : this(name)`.`this` mean you will use another constructor from same class

Comment: You can also use base() constructor in this chaining constructors. Just a tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What 'this' keyword is referring from current instance of the class when you use it with chaining constructors?

It refers to a constructor call from **this** class (in comparison to constructors from the **base** class).

Comment: Oh ok, one more thing I want to ask, when I allocate object of some Class on managed heap (so allocate to memory), does it store just information about data in data fields or is in memory saved object that contains data fields + all members of class? (method, constructors and so on...)

Comment: All members should be referenced some how for later using - so all members will be stored

Answer (score 2):

```
public MyClass(string name, string id) : this(name)
```

`this` mean you will use another overload constructor from same class.

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string name) : this(name, 0) // will call constructor with two arguments
    { }

    public Person(string name, string id)
    {
        Name = name;
        Id = id;
    }        
}
```

Comment: I would love to ask one more question, if I get this sentence right, Does:  "refers to the current instance of the class" actually means that it refers to instance that you have in memory and you currently "using"?

Comment: Yes. Think about `this` like scope which have access to all members inside `class MyClass { ... }` and of course possible derived members from base class